# Michelson-Morley interferometer in free fall

Tags: general-relativity, optics, equivalence-principle, free-fall, interferometry

We suppose that we have a Michelson-Morley interferometer in free fall, will there be no interference: the round trip time in both arms of the interferometer is the same?

Comment: Where is the observer? Is the observer also in free fall with the system?

Comment: Of course, thank you for specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Michelson Morley interferometer will have no interference in free fall.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you know?  (a reference please)

Comment: The LISA Pathfinder mission achieved sub-picometer accuracy in free fall. https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08924

Comment: Thank you very much even if it is not my goal but it is a very interesting experience and good to know

Comment: A long time ago I tried to change (accomodate) the Lorentz transformations for acceleration with: v'=γ(v-at), with: c²-a²t²=0, I got: t'(1)=T/[1-(at/c)] and t'(2)=T/[1-(at/c)] and t'(orthogonal)=T/[1-(a²t²/c²)]^(1/2),....   :-) but this is custom-made  DIY:-) (DL traduction, My level in English is average, I registered here to improve it, Arabic after French and now English and they say why we are behind (third world) !!!)

Comment: @TheTiler to get relativistic transformations between non-inertial frames it is best to use tensors. The Lorentz transformations for acceleration won't be meaningful

Comment: Yes, thank you, as the interferometer is in free fall, by the principle of equivalence of Einstein, we can locally cancel the gravitation by a change of reference frame and have an intertial reference frame